# How to read brackets literally (as a tuple) in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

When I type this have this code:

```
?- Tuple = ((2, 4), (2, 4)).
```

It says:

```
Tuple = ((2, 4), 2, 4).
```

But I would want it to say:

```
Tuple = ((2, 4), (2, 4)).
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It is the same. The comma operator is right-associative.  Think of (1+1)+1 and 1+1+1. They are exactly the same, because `+` is left-associative.

Comment: You are completely right.  `?- ((3, 2), (2, 3)) = ((3, 2), 2, 3).` answers: True. I should have figured it out by myself.

Comment: There is a universal method to check things: `write_canonical(Myterm)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to think of the comma-operator as making "tuples".  Pairs (as in your example) are still ok, but as you noticed, the syntax can be confusing because it hides the structure: `(1,(2,3))` is the same as `(1,2,3)` and the same as `1,2,3`.

Once you try making triplets you get into real trouble, because `(1,2,3)` is indistinguishable from the nested pairs `(1,(2,3))`.  That's of course because it really *is* a nested pair, not a flat structure.

It is better style to use a specific functor, let's say `t/N`. Then there is no ambiguity between `t(1,2,3)` and `t(1,t(2,3))`.